# Как настроить автоматическое включение windows?

Tags: windows, администрирование

Долго пытался настроить автоматическое включение ПК на windows 10. Я просто создал bat файл в котором написал привет (чтоб чтото было). Далее через планировщик задач установил время запуска bat файла. Пк запускается, но есть проблема. После включения даже работают программы на фоне (у меня через планировщик ещё одна программа запускается и по ней я понял что ПК полноценно работает), но экран не загорается и самое главное, через митуты так 3 он выключается. И естественно моя программа тоже выключается. Если это поможет, то перед включением он ещё сам и выключается (с этим я разобрался), я также через планировщик задач запускал bat файл. Внутри написанно shutdown  /h. Долго пытался найти решение и ничего не нашёл, буду очень благодарен, если поможете. Если знаете можете предлагать другие способы автоматического выключения и включения. Всем спасибо)

Comment: Проверьте в настройках плана электропитания, через какой промежуток происходит отключение экрана.

Comment: Отключение экрана через 10 мин.

Comment: Кстати при включении загорается стартовое окно (там написано Gigabyte вроде) и я думаю это проблема со стороны windows, т.к. загрузочных окон windows уже не показывает (только когда мышкой подёргаю он показывает кнопку войти) и он вроде не в режиме сна, т.к. в режиме сна моя программа не работает (я пробовал), а когда он через минуты так 3 выключается, то он выключается вроде как полностью (когда я дёргаю мышкой он не включается (только на нажатие кнопки вкл на ПК)).